# How to take multi line input form user and show the same in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, textarea

I have searched many articles but I could not find one appropriate. I am trying to take input form user a multiple line text and show them as it is. I am using textarea tag, but the page is not working the input values are showed in one line even it I press enter an start a new line.
Please help me fixing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) when echoing the output.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Can you please suggest me a book for PHP and MySQL? I am hardly finding everything in a book.

Answer (score 2):

Already mentioned `nl2br()` is one way;

another way is to echo the output within `<pre> .. </pre>` HTML tags.

Comment: nl2br is handy but <pre>..</pre> is also helpful. I thought pre tag will not work. but it works thanks..